# Django - Llamar a un archivo estático desde otro

Tags: javascript, python, django

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Django 2, en ella llamo a un archivo Javascript como a cualquier otro archivo estático. El problema viene cuando quiero llamar a otro archivo estático desde este Javascript, por ejemplo una foto que esta en la misma carpeta.

Por mucho que busco no encuentro una solución, si inserto el código directamente en el html funciona perfectamente, pero es una muy mala solución.

Este es mi esquema de proyecto:

[image: Esquema de proyecto]

Y esta es una de las llamadas que quiero hacer y que producen fallo:

```
// Loading assets
        preloader.preload = function() {

            Kiwi.State.prototype.preload.call( this );

            this.addImage( "loadingImage", "{% static 'js/loadingImage.png' %}", true );
        };
```

Comment: Estás usando el server de desarrollo (runserver) o en un stack de producción (nginx/apache + gunicorn/uwsgi/etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Directamente no se puede utilizar los "template tags" `{% static %}`  de django dentro de archivo javascript ya que solo el manejador de templates lee el html y no los estaticos.

Pero una solucion a tu problema puede ser [django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) que minifica todos los estaticos y aparte si tienes tags o variables dentro de ellos los puede sustituir.